# How can I freeze a column in a ClosedXML-generated Excel report for details but unfreeze it in summary and source summary sections?

Tags: c#, closedxml.report

I've generated an Excel report using the ClosedXML package in Visual Studio. The report contains sections for details, summary, and source summary. I've successfully frozen a column in the "details" section, but this freezing applies to the other sections as well. I'm seeking guidance on how to unfreeze the column specifically in the summary and source summary sections, while keeping it frozen in the details section. Any insights on achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Trying to unfreeze without adjusting the width of the cell